# Future.delayed and Timer are executing all of the delayed callbacks

Tags: flutter, dart

So this is the deal. I am using Places autocomplete API in my app, so in Textfield's onChanged function I am making request to it for each letter typed. This costs a lot and I tried using Future.delayed to delay this call. So I wrapped the whole function in Future.delayed and gave it a 2 seconds delay. Now it waits 2 seconds but after 2 seconds it executes all the delayed call.

Example:

typing: 'New York' (within 2 seconds)
result: waits 2 seconds and executes following: Ne, New, New , New Y, New Yo, New Yor, New York..

So basically it delays it but then executes it all at once. How do I solve this?

PS: I did try to wrap onchanged function itself as well the function responsible for api calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `onChanged` function will trigger on every change, meaning for every letter that is typed. `Future.delayed` does not change this behavior and instead delays every call of the function.

What you are looking for is debounce or throttle functions. Consider using a library such as [this](https://pub.dev/packages/debounce_throttle) that provides them.

Comment: Thanks for idea. I actually used this library as it seems to be simpler. https://pub.dev/packages/just_debounce_it